# Controller not registering when using ngRoute

Tags: angularjs

I am still new to angularJS, and I have a problem when using ngRoute on the same js file as one of my controller.

code:

index.html

```
<html  ng-app="testModule">
  <head></head>
  <body ng-controller="testController">
    <div>
      <h1> {{helloText}} </h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controller/test.js"></script>
    <script src="controller/testView1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
var testModule = angular.module("testModule",['ngRoute']);

testModule.controller("testController", function($scope) {
  $scope.helloText = "hello!";
});

testModule.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/page1', {
    templateUrl : 'view/test1.html',
    controller  : 'test1ViewController'
  });
});
```

testView1.js

```
angular.module("testModule").controller('test1ViewController',function($scope) {
  $scope.message1 = "this is a message from test1ViewController!";
});
```

test1.html

```
<div ng-controller="test1ViewController">
  <p>this is a message </p>
  {{message1}}
</div>
```

It does not show anything, and upon looking on the console:

> angular.js:14800 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=testController
>
> Error: $controller:ctrlreg A controller with this name is not
>   registered. 
>   The controller with the name 'testController' is not
>   registered.

I have also tried moving **testController** to **testView1.js**, and it works as it's supposed to do. Also the ngRoute still does not work. I don't know what to do about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some naming issues, not sure if that is just errors you created while posting, or if these exist in your project as well, but, for the html template you show `view/test1.html`, but in your example you say it named `test1.js`.

As far as why it doesn't seem to find `testController`. In your `testView1.js` file, you are re-initializing your angular app. That should just be adding the controller to your app, rather than creating a new app. In `test.js` you declare `testModule`, so we are going to use that in your other controller files.

testView1.js

```
testModule.controller('test1ViewController',function($scope) {
   $scope.message1 = "this is a message from test1ViewController!";
});
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I have updated it to test1.html.